# How to display multiple videos in a div using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I want to display multiple videos horizontally in a single div using angular.js.

I have kept all the videos in an array and trying to pull them out in a div in a horizontal manner.But out of three,I'm getting only one video in the entire div.

Remaining two videos are getting overrided.Can I use ng-repeat over here? Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue...

My html code :

```
<div class="panel-body">

                <video width=176 height=99 html5-video='{{ videoSources }}' autoplay='true'
                    controls='true'>
                </video>
                <br> <a href="#" ng-click='loadVideos()'>Load videos</a>

            </div>
```

My js code:

```
angular.module('Admin', ['media'])
.controller('Home', function($scope) {

    $scope.videoSources = [];

    $scope.loadVideos = function() {
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://localhost/Video/Digital_Hiring.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://localhost/Video/Customer_Service.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://localhost/Video/Digital_Hiring.mp4');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an `ng-repeat` directive to the `<video>` element like so:

```
<video ... html5-video="{{videoSource}}" ng-repeat="videoSource in videoSources track by $index">
```

The `track by $index` syntax is necessary in case there are two video source strings which have equal values (like in your question example code). It's also in my opinion better than wrapping the video in an additional `<div>`.

Here's a working example (removed the module dependency and added `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to the root div):

```js
angular.module('Admin', [])
  .controller('Home', function($scope) {

    $scope.videoSources = [];

    $scope.loadVideos = function() {
      $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/boat_149.webm');
      $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/horse_riding_205.webm');
      $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/flower_124.webm');
    };
  })
  .filter("trustUrl", ['$sce',
    function($sce) {
      return function(recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="Admin" ng-controller="Home">

  <video width=176 height=99 ng-repeat="videoSource in videoSources track by $index" autoplay controls ng-src="{{videoSource | trustUrl}}">
  </video>
  <br> <a href="#" ng-click='loadVideos()'>Load videos</a>

</div>
```

**Edit:** to get the videos to work, use `ng-src` and add the `.filter()` from the example (to trust the string we pass it as an url)

Comment: I'm able to get the videos horizontally.But the videos are not running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-repeat to repeat the video element for each video in the array.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div ng-repeat="video in videosources">
        <video width=176 height=99 html5-video='{{ video }}' autoplay='true'
                controls='true'>
        </video>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The div will now repeat for each video. Within that div, each of the "videosources" is referred to as "video". Angular will handle the rest.

The reason you were only seeing one is because you were referring to the whole array as a single item. It was probably displaying the first one.

Comment: If the divs are displaying vertically instead of horizontally, give the new div a class, and give that class a style of "float:left;" - they should line up one after the other. But thats getting a little off topic!

Comment: when I edit the above code,I'm unable to see the video

Comment: does the div repeat? If you are using Google Chrome you can right-click->inspect to see what is displaying.

Comment: also, videoSources should have a capital S in my code!

Comment: Here  this has got commented<!-- ngRepeat: video in videosources --> in google chrome inspect  and unable to see any video

Comment: it should be <div ng-repeat="video in videoSources">

Comment: Yes I have tried the same.But it is getting commented in the inspect element of google chrome.So,unable to display a video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97967/discussion-between-leon-and-gangigunta-divya).